# Getting "Invalid OAuth access token." response for /instagram_oembed endpoint using Instagram Graph API

Tags: oauth, instagram-api, oembed

"Invalid OAuth access token." for instagram_oembed

I have gone through the required steps to create an app, add "oEmbed Read" permissions to it, submit it for app review, get approved, and finally generate an access token.

To be clear, I was able to submit the app for review and get apprived. The "App Review Status" says "Live" for the `Oembed Read` feature. I have access to the `/instagram_oembed` endpoint according to the Permissions and Features section of my app.

[image: Screenshot showing valid permissions]

The very last step is getting a working access_token, and this is where I am stuck. I am following [these instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-access-tokens-and-permissions/).

I am able to generate a token but when I use it to request instagram posts like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/instagram_oembed?url={instagram_post_url}&access_token={access_token}
```

I get "Invalid OAuth access token."

[Debugging it via Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/)

It says the token is valid with the following scope: user_profile, user_media

I am also able to successfully exchange the "short-lived" token for a 3 month version, which also looks valid via the Access Token Debugger but also generates the same "invalid Oauth access token" response.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was following instructions for User Tokens, but what you need is an App Token.

See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens